# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/App.framework/App in xcode13.1

Tags: flutter

flutter:main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'));

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      locale: const Locale('zh', ''),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: ScmStartPage(),
    );
  }
}

class ScmStartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScmStartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScmStartPageState createState() => _ScmStartPageState();
}

class _ScmStartPageState extends State<ScmStartPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: Text('我是文本')),
    );
  }
}
```

swift project: AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
        
        return true
    }

}
```

swift project build crash :

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/App.framework/App   Referenced from:
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/8699A097-28EB-4B42-8566-994E5EC45F52/ceshiss.app/ceshiss
> Reason: image not found dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
> DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib

Comment: Hi, May I know if you are trying to add-to-app in flutter?

Comment: flutter module add in app

Answer (score 1):

You did write the flutter code but where you have written swift code in AppDelegate to start flutter module engine?

1. You should first create a flutter module.
2. Create a Native iOS app (may exist already).

Once your module is ready then link (integrate) with your native code using one of the following Options given in the below link.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

After that need to add Swift code to start your flutter module engine. Please check below link.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=engine-swift-tab

If you want to send data from native to flutter module then use plateform method channel.

**Note:** When you integrate flutter module with your native then make sure to not embed static library. **FlutterPluginRegistrant** is one of them. It will give you a crash on device launch.

Comment: It is normal before upgrading the macOS system and xcode. An error is reported only after upgrading macos12.0.1, this code is example demo code, provide for github flutter issue:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92896

Comment: Yes, latest xcode does have this embed library issue.
If you will add static library as embed the crash would occur.
Read Options B carefully from the shared first url.

Comment: I tried option B or crash

Comment: The problem has been solved, see:github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92896

Comment: recently encountered this issue, but the problem disappear after changing flutter sdk to beta. Please check below link, github.com/flutter/samples/issues/1004